# How do you manage and organize your stored procedures?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

How do you organize your stored procedures so you can easily find them and keep track of their dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to name them according to a convention. Typically {TableName}_{operation}{extra} where the extra part is optional.

For example: Product_Get, Product_Add, Product_Delete, Product_Update, Product_GetByName

Answer (score 0):

I'm strongly considering creating database projects so that I can version the stored procedures and avoid the confusion when deploying from development to production. Once they start getting out of synch with a large project, things can get difficult fast.

Answer (score 0):

I try and keep the name as close to possible to what an sp does. For example sp_Get* , sp_Set* , sp_Rep* etc. Though in certain context sp_ is superflous but due to lack of integration of source code control (my pet peeve) in Sybase , I use this nomenclature to keep track of them in my preferred source code control repository.